# Error: Could not load file or assembly 'AjaxContolToolKit'? Strong name signature could not be verified?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, c#-4.0, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I had formatted my disk fully and then reinstalled the windows. After reinstalling i had opened my project and run it. then it gave me this error.

> Could not load file or assembly 'AjaxControlToolkit' or one of its
>   dependencies. Strong name signature could not be verified.  The
>   assembly may have been tampered with, or it was delay signed but not
>   fully signed with the correct private key. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80131045)

There is blue underline under first line of text.

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MainMaster.master.cs" Inherits="MainMaster" %>
```

How to resolve this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the solution [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1043427.aspx). Best choice to solve this issue would be to delete the dll and re upload a new one in your project.